# PHP sending data fields POST

Tags: php, post, curl

I have a problem with sending post fields to the php script.

post.php:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://server.com/test.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "postvar1=value1&postvar2=value2");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec ($ch);
echo $result;
curl_close ($ch);

?>
```

test.php

```
<?php

$a = $_POST['postvar1'];
$b = $_POST['postvar2'];

echo "Result: ".$a." ".$b." !";

?>
```

Script seems to work properly. However, browser console shows GET request instead of POST and there are no data fields. How does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its posting from server to server . your browser cannot see that request. but your browsers request is a simple get to the first page.
you call

```
   http://server.com/post.php
```

might be  a get call.

Comment: One more question, how to observe incoming and outcoming request from each script.

Comment: you have to check the server log (access log).